# how to put two pictures side by side?

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, tikz-trees

I try to put the two pictures side by side using the following code, however, the size of the two pictures are very small like the picture.

[image]

However, the picture looks like if I don't put them together.
[image]

I don't know why.

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\resizebox{.6\textwidth}{!}{
\tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance=0.7cm, sibling distance=4.5cm}}
\tikzset{level 2/.style={level distance=0.7cm, sibling distance=5cm}}

\tikzset{bag/.style={text width=20em, text centered,yshift=-0.2cm}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down, -stealth,  edge from parent/.style={draw,decorate,decoration={snake, post=lineto, post length=3mm}}]
{\node[bag]{$S_0{:}(A{<}a{=1}{>}B,G_{t_{i_1}},0)$}
    child{ edge from parent node[right=0.1cm]{$$}; \node[bag]{$S_{n-1}{:}(stop_{good},t_{i_1}{\geq}2,0)$}
    }
    child{edge from parent node{$\times$}; \node[bag]{$S_n{:}(stop_{good},t_{i_3}{\geq}3,0)$}
    };
}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{A Circle}
\label{fig:circle}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\resizebox{.6\textwidth}{!}{
\tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance=0.7cm, sibling distance=4.5cm}}
\tikzset{level 2/.style={level distance=0.7cm, sibling distance=5cm}}

\tikzset{bag/.style={text width=20em, text centered,yshift=-0.2cm}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down, -stealth,  edge from parent/.style={draw,decorate,decoration={snake, post=lineto, post length=3mm}}]
{\node[bag]{$S_0{:}(A{<}a{=1}{>}B,G_{t_{i_1}},0)$}
    child{ edge from parent node[right=0.1cm]{$$}; \node[bag]{$S_{n-1}{:}(stop_{good},t_{i_1}{\geq}2,0)$}
    }
    child{edge from parent node{$\times$}; \node[bag]{$S_n{:}(stop_{good},t_{i_3}{\geq}3,0)$}
    };
}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{A Rectangle}
\label{fig:rectangle}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've resized the images with `\resizebox`. Part of the reason they're so small, is that within a `minipage`, `\textwidth` is set to the width of the `minipage`. Hence, when you set the width to be `0.6\textwidth` within a minipage that is `0.5\linewidth`, the width of the resizebox will be 0.3 of the `\linewidth` for the whole page.

In addition, because you've set the `text width` of the `bag` nodes to `20em`, there is some whitespace on the sides of each tree, and the size of the `\resizebox` includes this whitespace.

Also, please include full examples, including all packages and libraries. Makes it easier for trying to help, not having to figure out which `decorations` library is missing.

See if this is a little better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{bag/.style={text width=10em, text centered,yshift=-0.2cm}}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
\the\textwidth
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\the\textwidth
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance=0.7cm, sibling distance=4.5cm}}
\tikzset{level 2/.style={level distance=0.7cm, sibling distance=5cm}}


\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down, -stealth,  edge from parent/.style={draw,decorate,decoration={snake, post=lineto, post length=3mm}}]
{\node[bag]{$S_0{:}(A{<}a{=1}{>}B,G_{t_{i_1}},0)$}
    child{ edge from parent node[right=0.1cm]{$$}; \node[bag]{$S_{n-1}{:}(stop_{good},t_{i_1}{\geq}2,0)$}
    }
    child{edge from parent node{$\times$}; \node[bag]{$S_n{:}(stop_{good},t_{i_3}{\geq}3,0)$}
    };
}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{A Circle}
\label{fig:circle}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance=0.7cm, sibling distance=4.5cm}}
\tikzset{level 2/.style={level distance=0.7cm, sibling distance=5cm}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down, -stealth,  edge from parent/.style={draw,decorate,decoration={snake, post=lineto, post length=3mm}}]
{\node[bag]{$S_0{:}(A{<}a{=1}{>}B,G_{t_{i_1}},0)$}
    child{ edge from parent node[right=0.1cm]{$$}; \node[bag]{$S_{n-1}{:}(stop_{good},t_{i_1}{\geq}2,0)$}
    }
    child{edge from parent node{$\times$}; \node[bag]{$S_n{:}(stop_{good},t_{i_3}{\geq}3,0)$}
    };
}+
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{A Rectangle}
\label{fig:rectangle}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, it does look bigger, however, still small:(

Comment: Of course, it's still resized -- the "original" is wider than `.5\linewidth`. You can of course make the `minipage`s wider, if having the figure protruding into the margin is no problem. If you don't want them resized, don't place them side by side.